# I had error like this 'TypeError: userContract.transfer is not a function'

Tags: web3js

This is my code.

```js
var userContract = new web3.eth.Contract(testABI, contractAddress);
let decimals = web3.utils.toBN(18);
// let amount = web3.utils.toBN(100);
// let value = amount.times(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals));
let value = web3.utils.toBN(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals));

userContract.transfer('0x' + receiver, value).send({
    from: myAccount, 
    gas: 0x00, 
    gasPrice: 0x00
}).then(receipt => {
    console.log("recipt ============ " + receipt);
    this.setState({"txHash": receipt});
});
```

If this code running, occurs an error.

TypeError: userContract.transfer is not a function

What means error?

Comment: If you want to call a function in your smart contract, you should use ```userContract.methods.methodName(args)```, otherwise it'll not work because contract instance from web3.js does not include a method called ```transfer```.

Comment: Could you use  this - methods.methodName(args) in web3 v 1.3.6?

Comment: In web3 v 1.x document, the function did not defined

Comment: Can you please update the question so we can understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to send ETH to another wallet address or do you want to call a function in your smart contract?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to send a token in my smart contract.

Comment: So, I am assuming you have a method called ```transfer``` in your smart contract. To call this method, you should use ```userContract.methods.transfer('0x' + receiver, value).send({...}).then(...)```.

Comment: But I had occurred.  userContract.methods.transfer is not a function. Do you know another method?